# Creating a native contact with read only fields

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my android app on 4.2.1 I want to create a contact with some read only fields. For example, the contact the app creates has a home phone number which is read only in the UI. I will create a separate account where all these contacts are created.

I was looking at the android documentation and understand that all these contact fields become part of the [Data table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html). But I dont see any column which can make the field read only.

Comment: I am not OP, but perhaps I can clarify since there is a response below that doesn't quite address the problem. The question is not about how to prevent other apps from writing over the data. The question is how to prevent editing in the UI, like Google+ does with its email address data (it is uneditable from the People app).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this. Apps that work with the Contacts Provider have to request permission to write to it. If the user grants this permission to the app, then it can write to the Contacts provider.

The only thing you can do is create your own MIME type for the Data table, encrypt the data, and store each piece of data in a row that has that MIME type. Other apps can still see your data, but they have no way of figuring out what it is.

The Contacts Provider is a public repository, and you have to use it according to the rules it provides.

Comment: This does not answer my question. My intention is not to hide the data but make it read only for the user. Like in the example I said in my question, - I create a contact via sync manager and add a phone number to it. While that phone number is visible to the user in the contacts app but the user cant edit it.